# MSAL Authentication: 401 and client_assertion' or 'client_secret' missing in POST request body

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Im getting 2 different errors on calling my login() function which looks like this:

```js
login() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType === InteractionType.Popup) {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
        this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as PopupRequest)
          .subscribe(() => this.checkAccount());
        } else {
          this.authService.loginPopup()
            .subscribe(() => this.checkAccount());
      }
    } else {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
        this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as RedirectRequest);
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup();
      }
    }
  }
```

I get these two errors:
[image: Errors]

I pretty much copied the authentication flow from this repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi This is officially from Azure and I set up everything like they did in the setup section of the readme. So the `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts` look the same of course with the replaced environment variables of my tenant and clientIDs. I also used the same package version (msal-angular@^2.0.0-alpha.3).

It would be greatly appreciated if you have any hints or ideas on these errors.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this error, you need to set the redirect URI used in your app to be of type "Single Page Application" in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your answer & work on MSAL! This resolved my issue.